# Cocos2d js Slot Game gets slows on large screen size

Tags: html, cocos2d-js

I have made slot games using Cocos2d js, but it slows down when spinning on large screen.
any help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some standards for developing games for HTML5 using Cocos2d-js

Like

1 - Canvas size should not increase 1920x1080 for PC and 980x450 for mobile devices.

2 - Assets size for mobile should be 30MB at most and for PC you can extend to 200MB.

3 - Choose director content scale factor if you are supporting multi resolution.

```
cc.director.setContentScaleFactor(scaleFactor)
```

4 - Avoid clipping node

5 - Use cocos action to spin reel.

6 - Do not try something like having 4 symbols at a time in one column for 3x3 slot and updating position of last ( down most ) symbol to top. Its you own logic to develop good and seamless game.

7 - Prefer 8 or 16 bit Images

8 - Use sprite sheet for packing images. You can use cocos studio

9 - Use bitmap text

10 - Use audio sprite

11 - Use scene transitions for switching scenes in your game

And after these. It depends on you how effciently you code.